# In log files what is the meaning of: s c sc cs?

Tags: asp.net, file, iis, logging, file-format

Like [here on TechNet](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/676400bc-8969-4aa7-851a-9319490a9bbb.mspx?mfr=true) - under the "Appears As" column - **c**-ip, **cs**-uri-query, etc.

(I got a log file where the columns are described that way but I don't understand those prefix letters.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **c**: client (e.g. `c-ip`, the IP address of the client)
- **s**: server (e.g. `s-ip`, the IP address of the server)
- **cs**: from client to server (e.g. `cs-bytes`, the number of bytes sent to the server)
- **sc**: from server to client (e.g. `sc-bytes`, the number of bytes sent to the client)